# Question about Remix warnings: gas cost and same name of variable

Tags: remix, warnings

When I try to compile the following contract on Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.9;
contract good{
   mapping (address =>uint) public balances;
   function withdraw () public {
      uint balance = balances [ msg . sender ];
      balances [ msg . sender ] = 0;
      msg . sender . transfer ( balance );
   }
// state reverted , balance restored if transfer fails
}
```

I am getting the two warnings:

> 1. Gas costs: Gas requirement of function good.withdraw is infinite:
>    If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas
>    limit, it cannot be executed.  Please avoid loops in your functions or
>    actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or
>    copying arrays in storage)

Why the gas cost is infinite? I am not using 'call'?

> 2)same name of var good.withdraw() : Variables have very similar names
> "balance" and "balances". Pos: 5:6:

Will the EVM consider balance and balances as same or is this just a Remix issue?

Zulfi.